# In PHP (plphp), how can we manage a file stored in a bytea with Imagick?

Tags: php, postgresql, imagemagick, imagick

We are storing entire image files in PostgreSQL, using bytea columns.

In PHP, am trying to open an image file from the bytea field (these stored as hex), then want to manipulate/convert the image using Imagick.

Must the bytestream be converted out of hex to be manageable - in a file-like way - by Imagick? Is there any other secret sauce?

I wouldn't be surprised if we had to read beyond the file header bits, either. Offending snippet is below:

```
// Decode image from hex?
$image = new Imagick ($row['thewholefile']);
// ERROR:  Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'Unable to read the file: /x0000000 (etc)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the problem here had to do with PostgreSQL's bytea presentation format- as we are using v9.n of PG, the default output is hex:

We had to first set output to PG's 'Old School' bytea handling. Then, by pg-unescaping the raw column data, we had something we could work with:

```
SET bytea_output = 'escape'

$unescaped   = pg_unescape_bytea($content);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need readimageblob. Here you go:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagick-readimageblob.php

Comment: Tks for your response here - though not really the problem I was dealing with, readimageblob is certainly part of the _overall_ solution.

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty clear, just as the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagick-construct.php): the constructor requires a filename or an array of filenames. Use Jauzsika's solution.